# DAX Studio - Expression specified in the query is not a valid table expression

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I have a [code](https://www.daxpatterns.com/currency-conversion/) and outcome as below

```
EVALUATE
VAR AggregatedSalesInCurrency =
ADDCOLUMNS (
SUMMARIZE(
    'OPC SUMMARY (2)',
    'Calendar'[Date],
    'dimCurrency'[Currency Code]

),

        "@SalesAmountInCurrency", [Sales (Internal)],
        
        "@Rate", CALCULATE ( 
                 SELECTEDVALUE ( 'factFX'[FX Rate] )
        )
    )
RETURN
AggregatedSalesInCurrency
```

[image: outcome table]

But if I add the SUMX function say `the expression specified in the query is not a valid table expression`  why would that be? many thanks in advance.

```
   EVALUATE
VAR AggregatedSalesInCurrency =
ADDCOLUMNS (
SUMMARIZE(
    'OPC SUMMARY (2)',
    'Calendar'[Date],
    'dimCurrency'[Currency Code]

),

        "@SalesAmountInCurrency", [Sales (Internal)],
        
        "@Rate", CALCULATE ( 
                 SELECTEDVALUE ( 'factFX'[FX Rate] )
        )
    )
//RETURN
//AggregatedSalesInCurrency


VAR Result =
    SUMX (
        AggregatedSalesInCurrency,
        [@SalesAmountInCurrency] / [@Rate]
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in DAX Studio and so need to return a table. Try wrapping your return in curly braces.

```
RETURN
    {Result}
```

Comment: thanks, but it returns Nan.